# form submit not working in firefox , works fine in chrome

Tags: php, html, forms, firefox

I am fetching data from database , each rowof data creates a form , each row has a "book" button, which submits phase and site data, but this "book" button does not work in Firefox and IE , **it works in  chrome**

```
<?php
echo"<div style='overflow-y:scroll;height:200px;float:left;' ><table border=1 >
    <tr>
    <td>phase</td> <td>site no.</td> <td>plot-size</td> <td>face</td> <td>sply</td> <td>status</td><td>select </td>
    </tr>" ;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ret, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<tr>".
            "<form action='restricted.php' method='get'>".
            "<td><input type='text' value=\"{$row['phase']}\" name='phase' size='3' readonly />  </td>".
             "<td><input type='text' value=\"{$row['id']}\" name='site' size='4' readonly /></td>".
             "<td> {$row['size']} </td>".
             "<td> {$row['facing']} </td>".
             "<td>{$row['sply']} </td> ".
             "<td>{$row['status']} </td> ".
             "<td><input type='submit' name='book' value='book' \" /></td>".
             "</form>".
             "</tr>";   

    } 
    echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

Comment: try by putting a different name attribute in your form for every row.

Comment: one method would be to set a counter before while loop and change your form code to `<form action='restricted.php' method='get' name='form-{$counter}'>` and increase the counter afterwards.

Comment: adding name did not help

Comment: There is a stray quote in the submit tag, near the end. What's it doing there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot have a form within a `<tr>` element. You must either put the form outside the table, or inside a `<td>` element. Firefox is probably complaining about that.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Do you have any references to back that up? This is a common practice from I can tell.

Comment: @MrLister thanks, I must learn to proof read. Yes, do a quick google of form within table - it is invalid markup. I can't guarantee this is why Firefox is complaining though.

Comment: @ZackNewsham, thanks for your answer, this helped me save countless hours of debugging. I think all Web Developers and Designers should you use Firefox as their defacto browser to develop websites for its follows strict standards which in turn helps to code better rather than Chrome which leave loose ends.